# Selenium find available options of dropbox

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Good day!
I am trying to create Tests for website and I am using Selenium.
I've been stuck on an issue, where I have a dropbox and I want to get all available options in it and compare to the ones there should be.
The problem is that the structure of website is a lot of nested divs and when inspecting code I can't understand which div corresponds to my dropbox as it is highlighted in several different divs.
Moreover, I am unable to use Select class as it can not be used on div element.
I found a what supposed to be workaround (code below), but it did not work as I keep getting None type after click:

```
listWE = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="FXOptions"]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div'))).click()
print(listWE)
ab = Select(listWE)

None
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/18356995/Documents/WebUI/selenium/main.py", line 28, in <module>
    ab = Select(listWE)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/support/select.py", line 36, in __init__
    if webelement.tag_name.lower() != "select":
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'tag_name'
```

I've tried inspecting and object and copying its Path, I've tried coping the Path of all divs corresponding to my Dropbox but result is the same.

Below is website structure

[image]

Comment: have you tried to use css_selector instead of xpath? if you provide page url I'll try to help you.

Comment: @RiccardoLamera unfortunately page can be viewed only in my corporate network. I have not tried css_selector but if it might help - I will

Comment: `driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div.ant-col.ant-col-20.ant-form-item-control')` you can use to look for divs. You can click on them (I suggest that you use `driver.excute_script` to do the click). In case you have divs with same class name, use xpaths such as `"div[@class='...']//span[@class='...']//...`